# Running Subversion under Apache with two different versions of Subversion Server

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, subversion-edge

We have five completely separate Subversion repositories on one server, and we use Apache httpd as our Subversion server. I do this because I can incorporate LDAP and use our Windows Active Directory for read/commit access.

Our Subversion server is at revision 1.7.6. One of the repositories is our development repository and is very, very big: Over 200 users and is about 10 Gigabytes in size. There are over 80 separate *projects* on it. Another one, our training repository is very small. Maybe 1/2 dozen users and very few changes.

Our training group uses MadCap Flair which uses SVN on the backend. After upgrading to version 10, they noticed Flair was taking a long, long time to update. MadCap told them that the Subversion server had to be upgraded to at least version 1.8.5.

Let me repeat:

- One big hulking repo with hundreds of users -- no problems with 1.7.6.
- One teeny-tiny repo with five or six users who need to upgrade to 1.8.5.

You can see I'm a bit hesitant to upgrade our server to 1.8.5 just for this one group. We'll probably do it sooner or later anyway, but when it's when our development cycle has some slack.

I could install a second copy of Subversion (We're using SubversionEdge) in a different location on the same server, and use `svnserve` now that I can use SASL with LDAP. This would allow me to serve that one repository with `svnserve` at revision 1.8.5 while the other three repos would remain untouched for now. However, the training group would have to redo their Madcap setup.

In order to be able to keep their Madcap setup I see two possibilities:

- Somehow run that single Apache instance with two separate versions of Subversion.
- Run a second Apache server (it could be on a different machine), but somehow setup redirects to that `http://svn/train` is redirected to a second Apache server.

Is the first one even possible? Is it possible to have the following URLS go to two completely different servers?

- `http://svn/dev` - Goes to our current server and Development repo.
- `http://svn/qa` - Goes to our current server and QA repo.
- `http://svn/train` - Goes to another server, but with the same training repo.